# How do I update dictionary to another nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to add dictionary with new key to another dictionary but I don't know how to code in python

For example, if I have two dictionary like this:

```
dic_A = {"A": a, "B": b}
dic_C = {"E": e, "F": f}
```

And I want to add dic_C to dic_A with new key "C" as nested dictionary like this:

```
dic_A = {"A": a, "B": b, "C": {"E": e, "F": f}}
```

Comment: `dic_A['C'] = dic_C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new Key in `dic_A` with values of `dic_C` as below.

```
dic_A['c'] = dic_C
```